# auto repeat javascript function in browser until terminating input entered

Tags: javascript, function, browser, repeat

I've been trying to have a simple multiplication table program repeat until a "-1" is entered. I've tried different variations of several loops but the most success I've had is only repeating the prompt questions.  The code works as desired until I try to have it repeat. The following code is the working version as a one time run program. Any help appreciated.

```
function getVariables(){
    var table = parseInt(prompt("Enter table: "));
    var start = parseInt(prompt("Enter start: "));
    var end = parseInt(prompt("Enter end: "));

    if (isNaN(table) || isNaN(start) || isNaN(end)) {
        alert("Please enter numerical integers only");

        getVariables();
    }
    else {
        timesTable(table, start, end);
    }
}

function timesTable(table, start, end) {
    for (;start <= end; start++) {
        document.write(table + " * " + start + " = " + table * start     + "<br/>");
    }
}

var proceed = prompt("Do you want to display times tables? Press  'ENTER' to continue or enter '-1' to exit.");

if (proceed != -1){
    getVariables();
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write

Answer (score 0):

For a yes/no question you should use `confirm()`, not `prompt()`.

```
while (confirm("Do you want to display times tables?")) {
    getVariables();
}
```

But if you want to use `prompt`, it's

```
while (prompt("Do you want to display times tables? Press  'ENTER' to continue or enter '-1' to exit.") == '-1') {
    getVariables();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Barmar !  I previously tried the "while(prompt)" version but this repeatedly executes the prompt questions. Only after the "-1" is entered does it display the multiplication table.  Also, when i try the "while(confirm)" version it doesn't allow for the "-1" I need and results in an endless loop.  I cannot figure out why the "while loop" will not execute the entire program before repeating the prompts.

Comment: That's because the browser doesn't redisplay the DOM until after all the Javascript finishes. As long as you're in the Javascript loop you won't see anything in the browser window.

Comment: Instead of using a loop, use a button on the web page. When the user clicks on the button, run your `timesTable` function.

Comment: I guess my real question i how to redisplay the DOM then. I'll keep researching

Comment: You also should not use `document.write()`, that's 20th-century Javascript. You should use DOM modification functions. Maybe learn jQuery, it makes it easier to write things like this.

Comment: I do think the button would be much more practical, however that's not what my test problem asked for, unless i misread it.  Thanks for your input though, you've been helpful!  I'm working through the book "Beginning JavaScript" so it probably is outdated